# After end of daylight saving time, no CRON triggers occur except one

Tags: quartz.net

In our .NET application, we have several hourly job triggers:

- `XX:00`
- `XX:05`
- `XX:10`
- `XX:15`

During the end of DST (25 October 2020 at 03:00) the triggers stopped working except the first trigger (`XX:00`).

Hour `00` did well. Hour `01` also did well. But starting with hour `02` only the trigger at `02:00` worked. The three other triggers never got triggered, even later during the day it didn't work. They completely stopped working except the trigger for `XX:00` kept working.

I can't clarify why it behaved like this, because DST ended at `03:00` so I think `02:00` should have worked normally until `03:00`. Probably after `03:00` I should have seen some misbehaviour but the misbehaving happened at hour `02` as I mentioned earlier.

I'm very flexible in solving this issue. I can change the schedules to semi-hourly or to 2-hourly if it solves the issue. The 4 triggers just have to keep triggering instead of stopping completely... It doesn't matter when they run, as long as they trigger approximately every hour continuously. But `SimpleTrigger` isn't the one that I want to use, because then all the jobs start immediately in parallel when service starts and I don't want that...

I know there are similar questions here on SO, but in most of those questions the timing is stubborn. In my case, I'm very flexible and I'm looking for the easiest workaround.

Is there any quick workaround to solve this issue? Can I for example completely ignore DST and just use UTC?

Using library version: 3.0.7

The CRON triggers:

```
 0 0 * ? * * *
 0 5 * ? * * *
 0 10 * ? * * *
 0 15 * ? * * *
```